# NLog with NLog.Targets.Syslog - Object reference error

Tags: nlog

I'am trying to log to the papertrail systems using NLog and NLog.Targets.Syslog and somehow NLog fails to load the target from the NLog.config when I call

```cs
Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

and throws the exception
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```cs
at NLog.Targets.Syslog.Settings.Rfc3164Config..ctor()
   at NLog.Targets.Syslog.Settings.MessageBuilderConfig..ctor()
   at NLog.Targets.Syslog.SyslogTarget..ctor()
```

Stacktrace

```cs
at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.Initialize(XmlReader reader, String fileName, Boolean ignoreErrors)
   at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration..ctor(String fileName, Boolean ignoreErrors, LogFactory logFactory)
   at NLog.LogFactory.LoadLoggingConfiguration(String configFile)
   at NLog.LogFactory.get_Configuration()
   at NLog.LogFactory.GetLogger(LoggerCacheKey cacheKey)
   at NLog.LogFactory.GetLogger(String name)
   at NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()
   at NLogPaperTrail.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in I:\Temp\Proj\tempsolution\NLogPaperTrail\NLogPaperTrail\Controllers
```

This is the NLog.config

```xml
    <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" autoReload="true"     ThrowExceptions = "true"  >

 <extensions>

       <add assembly="NLog.Targets.Syslog" />
    </extensions>

    <targets>
        <target name="syslog" xsi:type="Syslog" syslogserver="host.papertrailapp.com" port="5677" facility="Local7"/>

   </targets>

    <rules>

     <logger name="*" minLevel="Trace" appendTo="syslog"/>
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

Can anyone help or provide your suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Also reported here:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/1894

And resolved here (SysLog Target Ver. 3.0.1)

https://github.com/graffen/NLog.Targets.Syslog/pull/53